# VIM autocommand to clone file to a new unit with similar folder path

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

i'm looking for an autocommand with vim that clones my working file to my 'production' destination. Ex.:
My source file is -> C:\Web\myApp\js\example.js
And would like to clone file to -> E:\root\Product\Web\myApp\js\example.js.

I need to respect part of the folder source path to destination ('myApp\js\') .
Using windows.

Comment: When should this autocommand be executed, on saving?

Comment: i was thinking in a custom vim keyword for that. Do you now any way or any plugin that can automatize that?